# Can I change total price before $this->context->cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH); ?

Tags: prestashop, cart, prestashop-1.6

I was wondering if the total price could change before:
$ This-> context-> cart-> getOrderTotal (true, Cart :: BOTH);

If it's $ 20, add another $ 10 to the total price. What is the way to do that?

Comment: Override the getOrderTotal :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply after long wandering on the code and I came to this option :)